# I'm getting an error in my Java code but I can't see whats wrong with it. Help?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

The error i'm getting is in the fillPayroll() method in the while loop where it says payroll.add(employee).  The error says I can't invoke add() on an array type Person but the Employee class inherits from Person so I thought this would be possible.  Can anyone clarify this for me?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Payroll
{   
    private int monthlyPay, tax;
    private Person [] payroll = new Person [1];

        //Method adds person to payroll array
    public void add(Person person)
    {
        if(payroll[0] == null) //If array is empty, fill first element with person
        {
            payroll[payroll.length-1] = person;
        }
        else //Creates copy of payroll with new person added
        {
            Person [] newPayroll = new Person [payroll.length+1];
            for(int i = 0;i<payroll.length;i++)
            {
                newPayroll[i] = payroll[i];
            }
            newPayroll[newPayroll.length] = person;
            payroll = newPayroll;
        }
    }


    public void fillPayroll()
    {
        try
        {
            FileReader fromEmployee = new FileReader ("EmployeeData.txt");
            Scanner data = new Scanner(fromEmployee);
                        Employee employee = new Employee();

            while (data.hasNextLine())
            {
                employee.readData(data.nextLine());
                payroll.add(employee);
            }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: File Not Found");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using an array use an `ArrayList`. You'll be much happier.

Arrays cannot be resized once created. All the boilerplate for managing that is done by `ArrayList`. Using arrays with subclasses in elements has other issues too (around covariance). Probably the only line you need to change is:

```
private final List<Person> payroll = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

`List`s have an `add()` method. Arrays don't.

Comment: Just look at me! I use `ArrayLists` all the time and I'm *very happy*! It really works!

Comment: If you don't have a one-track mind, you may need to use Vectors instead to be truly happy.

Answer (score 4):

If for whatever reason you can't use collections. you want to turn:

```
payroll.add(employee);
```

in to:

```
this.add(employee);
```

Answer (score 3):

payroll is an array. You are invoking method on an array. This is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

Since payroll is an array it would need to be

```
payroll[index].add(employee);
```

Comment: No, then you'd be adding an Employee to a Person.

Comment: This is absolutely not true! :S "payroll[index]" returns a "Person" instance... then you'd be calling "add" method on that "Person" instance! What he wants is to add a new "Person" instance to a "Persons" collection.

Comment: Agreed, his design is bad. Payroll needs to be List<Employee> payroll and not Person[] payroll;

Answer (score -1):

If Class B extends A:

> A a=new B();

but not:

> B b=new A();

Comment: if Employee extends Person, Employee is a Person. So Person ed = new Employee() is fine. You've got it backwards.